# Bitcoin prices in Japan are on the high side and there is an arbitrage window. Is it possible to arbitrage?

Tags: arbitrage

Recently, the price of Bitcoin has fluctuated sharply, and arbitrage windows have appeared on many exchanges. The price of Bitcoin on Binance is US$47,000, while on some exchanges in Japan, the price of Bitcoin is US$51,000. If you buy in Binance and then sell in Japan, you can make a profit of $4,000. I am considering doing this. I want to hear your opinion.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bitcoin arbitrage](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/76037/bitcoin-arbitrage). See also answers to other [questions about arbitrage](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/search?q=arbitrage)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/12670/5406

Comment: You may want to listen to [this](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2021-04-01/the-ex-jane-street-trader-who-s-building-a-multi-billion-crypto-empire) interview with Bankman-Fried.